# Is there a java function that emulates C's crypt functions?

Tags: java, c, encryption, cryptography, crypt

I am trying to create a password cracker that encrypts possible passwords and compares them to fake user passwords. To do this, I need to use the crypt function*, which would be easy if I was using c, but I'm using java. Is there an equivalent option? If so, where can I download it?

*Before you tell me it's insecure, I know. I'm using it for a lab and not an actual verification system.

Comment: you can always use C/C++ in Java with the JNI.

Comment: From [what I've read](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/crypt.html#crypt), `crypt()` produces hashes based on MD5 or DES. Both algorithms are available in Java's crypto libraries, so it's just a matter of rewriting the rest of the functions.

Comment: Google "java crypt implementation".

Comment: PS high performance crypto *is* a good reason to go native. Java isn't that fast compared with cryptography when compared to native implementations, especially if the native implementation use vector instructions or GPU resources.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're talking about the version available in glibc2, it supports more than DES encryption: not just encryption but also cryptographic digests.

You could in theory investigate the implementation details of `crypt()` to mimic its behaviour in Java. Encryption would typically be done using the [`Cipher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) class, and digest would be done using the [`MessageDigest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) class. You'll find that the algorithms you need are available with the [SUN and SunJCE providers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) that come with the Oracle/OpenJDK JRE (and probably others).

Getting the details right might require a bit of investigation (to find out how the salt is used, for example).

You could also directly use the [Apache Commons Codecs `Crypt`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/Crypt.html) class, which is specifically intended to be compatible with GNU libc crypt(3).

Comment: @owlstead, I guess the Apache Commons class could be a good starting point, couldn't it?

Comment: Uh, yes, that is probably the best way. Missed that one.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using this crypt function (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/crypt.html)

First of all, if you need to write code which will be exact equivalent, you will need to find how this function works inside.

Here is example of DES encryption (which is used by crypt):
http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/desstring.html

Here is example of MD5 hashing (which could be used by crypt):
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-md5-hashing-example/